# JAVA-Jersey and URI containing two forward slashes '//'

Tags: java, eclipse, jersey, uri

I have a JAVA code utilizing Jersey lib as the following...

```
ClientResponse response = resource().path("books//scifi").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).PUT(ClientResponse.class)
```

Result

1. I got 'books/scifi' as the return for ClientResponse - called via Eclipse-Run As on Windows.
2. I got 'books//scifi' as the return for ClientResponse - called via JAVA command on
       Linux.

Question Point

-What's the factor that bring these two different returns (as now I guess it may be the OS different encoding style.).

-In case that I want to make sure that I will always get Result-2 as the return ClientResponse on any environment, Is there any API configuration allow me to do this?